# Bookmarklet works in all browser except Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, bookmarklet

I have a bookmarklet in which I attempt to load a script from a remote server, then execute some code after the script loads. A stripped-down example can be seen below:

```
(function () {
    var url = '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js';

    var injectExtensionScript = function (path) {
        alert('injectExtensionScript');

        var element = document.createElement('script');
        element.type = 'text/javascript';
        element.src = path;

        document.addEventListener('load', function () {
            alert('loaded jquery');
        }, true);

        document.head.appendChild(element);
    };

    document.head.setAttribute('data-foobar', 123);

    injectExtensionScript(url);
})();
```

(minified for bookmarklet)

```
javascript:(function()%7B(function%20()%20%7Bvar%20url%20%3D%20'%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fjquery%2F1.9.0%2Fjquery.min.js'%3Bvar%20injectExtensionScript%20%3D%20function%20(path)%20%7Balert('injectExtensionScript')%3Bvar%20element%20%3D%20document.createElement('script')%3Belement.type%20%3D%20'text%2Fjavascript'%3Belement.src%20%3D%20path%3Bdocument.addEventListener('load'%2C%20function%20()%20%7Balert('loaded%20jquery')%3B%7D%2C%20true)%3Bdocument.head.appendChild(element)%3B%7D%3Bdocument.head.setAttribute('data-foobar'%2C%20123)%3BinjectExtensionScript(url)%3B%7D)()%7D)()
```

Adding this bookmarklet to Chrome, Safari and IE the code works as expected -- the "data-foobar" attribute gets added to the document head, and the script loads (and my event listener fires).

However, Firefox is a different story altogether. The script appears to run (no errors, and the first `alert()` fires... but the "data-foobar" attribute is *not* added to the document head, nor is the script ever loaded (network tab never records a request, and event listener never fires).

I don't think this is the same bug as [Bug 866522 - Bookmarklets affected by CSP](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=866522) because the sites I'm trying this on are not using a CSP.

Any ideas?

---

Specs: OSX 10.10.2, Firefox 39. Standard settings, except:
  * I block popups, 
  * do-not-track, 
  * never remember history, 
  * warn me when sites try to install add-ons
  * block reported attack sites
  * block reported web forgeries
  * NOT set as my default browser
  * Flash not installed

Comment: I think this is a security "feature" ... try pasting `javascript:` in firefox address bar. you can't, you have to type that part yourself

Comment: If it _is_ CSP it will show up in the web console. Aside from that, I guess it depends on the website since it works for me (FF 39 on Mac) on sites that don't specifically use CSP.

Comment: @robertklep interesting, it does not work for me at all using Fx 39 on Mac -- attempted from my own website (http://www.akawebdesign.com/) and no request made. Nothing shown in console.

Comment: @JaromandaX if it's part of the bookmarklet url, the `javascript:` part is fine. I hit the first `alert()` statement, but the subsequent stuff never seems to run.

Comment: @arthurakay - you have a point. bookmarklet works for me just fine. Are you trying to load it in a http or a https page?

Comment: @JaromandaX regular HTTP, no CSP. Absolutely nothing special about the page I'm trying to run it on, I get the same result on every page I've tried (multiple domains).

Comment: I'm wondering if it's actually a bug, or just some impossible-to-find setting in Firefox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, having the checkbox "Load this bookmark in the sidebar" checked seemed to be the problem. I don't know how that happened.